# Serialize - Data for Model class not passing to another Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, serialization, pojo

I have made my model class Serializable by implementing interface **Serializable**

Am also made all the nested class Serializable.

Created Intent as below :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,AddinquiryActvity.class);
intent.putExtra("sampleObject",inquiryDetailsModel);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

And Receiving it in another activity as below :

```
    Intent i = getIntent();
    InquiryDetailsModel inquiryDetailsModel = (InquiryDetailsModel) i.getSerializableExtra("sampleObject");
    if(inquiryDetailsModel!=null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully get", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully not get", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

But, always getting null for the **inquiryDetailsModel**

What might be the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you put the serialization code. Also why are you serializing instead of parcelable?

Comment: IMHO, passing full model objects between activities is an anti-pattern in Android. Google is steering developers towards using more fragments and fewer activities. Even if there are technical reasons why these should remain separate activities, you could use a singleton repository for obtaining the model objects, then pass IDs between activities. Beyond that, you might want to examine the extras in the `Intent` in the debugger, to see if the problem is in creating the `Intent`, receiving the `Intent`, or in trying to extract this particular extra from the `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass Serializable use `Bundle`, like this snippet code

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("key", your_object);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

and in someclass

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if(b != null)
thumbs = (ObjectType) b.getSerializable("key");
```